# How do I make sure my color stays the same in my different .psd files?

Tags: rgb, adobe-photoshop, colors

I asked two Photoshop experts I know but they haven't got a clue because all my settings are exactly the same, in both files. (except the RGB type!)

- I use RGB color, 72DPI, 8 bits / channel.
- No adjustments (filters, like greyscale, etc ...) are selected / used.
- The layers are both normal, and opacity and fill are 100% (yes, in both files).

I took two screenshots, and you can see the difference:

[image]

[image]

Both colors are ff795d, but that doesn't matter, any color I use gives me the same problem: they both look different.

Now, I know the CMYK settings (see screenshots) are different, but when the settings are the same the color changes. Why is this happening and how do I solve this problem?

My guess is I'm working with different a type of RGB.

It's sRGB IE61966 - 2.1 in the file I created (file info > raw data) but I can't find that in the file that started with a screenshot.

If that's the problem, how do I change / convert the RGB, once the file is already open?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I didn't know that.

I found the answer. I was told to make sure the color profile was the same.
I looked at it again but both files were sRGB IE61966 - 2, and they still are.

But I dugg a little deeper and I found it. So even though both profiles were the same, they really weren't. 
I had to go to Edit > Assign Profile > and select sRGB IE61966 - 2  !
Apparently, Mac (colors) was selected for the 'screenshot' file and that caused the problem. I think this happens by default.

Assigning a profile does change the colors of the 'screenshot' file. 
That's no good, because I wanted to use the color picker. 
The way to deal with this problem is to keep it like it is (do not assign profile) and duplicate / move the layer to the sRGB IE61966 - 2 file, and use the color picker in that file. 
Which is how I did it before I started questioning everything :-) 
I now understand why those colors weren't the same.

Comment: If you have registered your Super User and Stack Overflow accounts should associate with each other so you can regain ownership of the question. You might have to to this manually, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Answer (score 0):

A you point out L a b and C M Y K values are different on each image.

4623864297 - L 72 a 42 b 38 C 0 M 54 Y 55

4624469754 - L 67 a 51 b 41 C 0 M 66 Y 63

However, there's not a 1:1 relationship between RGB and CMYK, so different CYMK values can produce the same RGB values.